# How to change font of only last character in cell?

Tags: excel, vba

i want to change font of last character in cell.
for this i have tried below code. But not working.
Please help.

```
Right(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Got answer now :)
Below is solution:

```
Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Characters(Len(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value), 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try This :

```
Sub ColorTextv()

   Dim i As Long
   Dim text As String
   ' Change as per your requrement. I used it for testing purpose
   text = Cells(1, 9).Value

   For i = 1 To Len(text)
    If i = Len(text) Then
    Cells(1, 9).Characters(i, 9).Font.ColorIndex = 3    
    'You can change by mentioning color also        
    'Cells(1, 9).Characters(i, 9).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
   Next

End Sub
```